# 'conditional' css in next/react

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to apply styling depending on the element's parameters. I've tried to search for "conditional css react", "conditional react style in css" and other similar queries.
My code below:
e.g.

```
<div class="ChatComponent_chatText__n2g6S">
    <span class="ChatComponent_message__e9Kqh" data-author="me">test me</span>
    <span class="ChatComponent_message__e9Kqh" data-author="other">test others</span>
</div>
```

and the css code

```
.message {
    background-color: #eef5f8;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.message [data-author="me"] {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #363795, #005C97);
    color: white;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

And the rendered image below:
[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to remove the space between the css selector and the parameter such as:

```
.message {
    background-color: #eef5f8;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.message[data-author="me"] {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #363795, #005C97);
    color: white;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

and the rendered image is below:
[image: rendered image]

Comment: please reduce the question and answer to a minimum